# Objective C Categories Equivalent In PHP

Tags: php, objective-c

Is there any chance there is an equivalent of Objective C [Categories](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html) in PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want to do is break a huge class definition up over multiple files, and it's *your class*, then you can do that with [traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php). Just define some of the methods in a trait in a different file and `use` it in your class:

```
trait FooBar_ExtraMethods {
    function foo () { return 'qux'; }
}

class FooBar {
    use FooBar__ExtraMethods;

    function bar () { return 'baz'; }
}
```

But if you want to add methods to somebody else's class, then there's simply no way to do that with vanilla PHP. Your choices are:

- Live with the fact that this isn't possible and just write a function that takes instances of the class instead of extending it.
- Use an extension to add the functionality into the language. Right now, the only contender is Dmitry Zenovich and Sara Golemon's Runkit. [Zenovich's fork](https://github.com/zenovich/runkit) currently seems to be better-maintained and generally superior to [Golemon's](http://git.php.net/?p=pecl/php/runkit.git;a=summary) (although Golemon's is the one hosted on PECL), and the instructions below use Zenovich's fork.

Suppose I have an existing user-defined class `Foo`...

```
class Foo {
    function methodA($arg) { return 2*$arg; }
}
```

I can add a method to it like this:

```
runkit_method_add('Foo', 'methodC', function ($arg) {
    return 5 * $this->methodA($arg);
});
```

and call it like an ordinary method:

```
$f = new Foo;
echo $f->methodC(2); // 20
```

A couple of caveats:

- You can't add methods to built-in classes. So if you want to use this to extend library-defined classes, you're good, but if you want to extend built-in classes like `DateTime`, you're out of luck.
- This isn't remotely idiomatic - indeed, Runkit's tagline is *"For all those things you.... probably shouldn't have been doing anyway....."*. I leave it to your judgement whether to let that deter you from doing it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a [trait](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php).

```
trait CarMaintenance{
    public function needsOilChange(){}
    public function changeOil(){}
    public function rotateTires(){}
    public function jumpBatteryUsingCar(){}
}

class Car {
    use CarMaintenance;
    public function startEngine() {}
    public function drive() {}
    public function turnLeft() {}
    public function turnRight() {}
}
```

But traits could be reused in other class and could have their own hierarchy tree.

Comment: Not even remotely the same thing. Categories let you add methods to already-existing classes, including built-in ones or ones from other people's libraries, without modifying the original class's code - similarly to adding methods to a built-in object's prototype in JavaScript. Traits do not offer this capability.